# How i cat to add new html element to $event.target with Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have page with list of elements. I want to show "copy" button near every elements if the mouse is over an element.
Now i can create "copy" button in element by this method:

```
  mouseovered(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('element')) {
      event.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        '<button class="copy-button"></button>');
    }
  }
```

mouseovered($event) - is a event on list

But i don't know how to delete this button when mouse is leave. And, how quickly it is will work?

Comment: you should keep your view and your model separate.  If your view needs to have a copy button, then add it and show it when needed instead of dynamically adding and removing content from your view.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, dynamically adding is need because list can be very long. <I don't want to create 5000 hidden button for 5000 elements))

Comment: well that sounds like an issue for your ngFor loop.  Sounds like you need pagination to limit the scope of visible records at a given point in time, no?  A User cant understand 5000 items at once....   so there is no need to render them all.  Might as well conserve resources by doing a scrolling pagination to render 20 and 20more as needed, or some other concept than 5000 items at once.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, yes, it is true. But I want to keep ability to search elements by ctrl+f, browser hotkey.

Comment: chewing through machine resources because of using a OS shortcut is not the correct answer, especially using an OS shortcut for a Web utility.  You can easily implement a search bar that accomplishes the functionality of ctrl+f, with better resource management. I mean, im not telling you what to do, but giving a suggestion to improve the use of your machines resources.

Comment: I think, you are right, and I will try to write search bar and pagination to limit the scope of visible records.Thank you for comments

Comment: No problem.  That is one of the issues on this site. We will solve problems, but sometimes we need to sit down and ask "why are people doing what they are doing" and maybe solve greater questions.  Thank you for considering my opinion.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an id for each of your elements, and declare a public attribute inside your component. 
This way, you can generate a bunch of buttons, and display them only on focus or hover.

Here is an example where your elements are inside a list element.

```html
<li> <button id="1" class="copy-button" [class.hidden]='isFocused!=this.id' (focus)="focusedId = this.id" (blur)="focusedId = null"> </button></li>
```

Comment: I have more that 5000 elements in list. And i do not want to create 5000 buttons for showing only one in one time

Comment: In that case, you can detect the blur (or loss of hover), and delete your button. suppose you give your button a fixed id, you can do something like : `let btnToRemove = document.getElementById('#copy-btn')`
Then remove if `btnToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(btnToRemove)`